# How to solve for $n: n \le 2^n a$?

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

How to solve this equation for $n$: $n \le 2^n a$?

> Note: $a$ is a positive constant.

My Method:
$\\
n \leqslant 2^n a\\
\lg {n} \leqslant  \lg{(2^n a)}\\
\lg{n} \leqslant \lg{a} + \lg{2^{n}}\\
\lg{n} - \lg{2^{n}} \leqslant \lg{a}\\
\lg{(\frac n {2^n·})} \leqslant \lg{a}\\
\frac n {2^n} \leqslant a$

I just reached the question statement. Unable to figure out how to solve this.

The origin of this question: I was trying to find the Big-$O$ complexity of a relation which demands to solve an inequality. The original value of $a$ is $2^{10}$. I want to know how to solve this equation to calculate the range of values of $n$ for which the above inequality is true.

Comment: What is $a$?  $\space$

Comment: 'a' is any constant

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar, this is not true for $a\le 0$.

Comment: $n$ is a positive integer I assume? If so, this can never be true if $a \leq 0$. Further, you should edit your question to include information about $n$, as well as describe what you've tried so far, where you're stuck, any ideas you have etc.

Comment: @AJStas I am sorry for not clarifying the question properly, 'a' is a positive constant.

Comment: Why is it still on hold? He has attempted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=a.2^x$

Its obvious that for all negative $x$, $g(x)$ lies above $f(x)$. (If $a>0$) Let's find where these two curves touch each other.

For touching case, let the curves meet at $(x_1,y_1)$. If they touch each other, then slope of tangent at that point is same for both curves.
That means, $$1=a\cdot 2^{x_1}\log 2$$ and $$2^{x_1}=\frac{1}{a\log 2}$$

$x_1$ satisfies $f(x)=g(x)$ as well. So,
$$x_1=a.2^{x_1}$$
$$x_1=\frac{1}{\log 2}$$

Plug this back in the first equation to get $$a=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{\log(2)}}\cdot \log(2)}$$
Hence, the two curves touch each other for the above value of $a$.

This gives you three cases.

For $a$ equal to the above value, the curves only touch each other.

For $a$ greater than the calculated value, there will be no solution

For $a$ lesser than the calculated value, then two solutions exist.

Comment: I actually need to know how to calculate the range of values of n for which the given inequality is true. As, for the value of 'a', I need to clarify something. I was actually solving a relation to calculate its Big-Oh complexity. While doing it, I came across this inequality and I was unable to solve it. So, the value of 'a' is actually known to me and I didn't bother to give it here, thus defined it as a positive constant. But if it helps, $a = 2^{10}$. I need to know how to calculate the range of values for which the above inequality is satisfied for this a.